# jQuery.animate not working within Facebook iFrame on IE8/IE9

Tags: jquery, facebook, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

I have an issue with jQuery.animate in IE8 and IE9, but! Only within the Facebook iFrame.
If I use my own iFrame there's no problem.

What I am trying to do is move an element 2 pixel and back, like so:

```
$("#car_box_1").animate({top: "56px"}, 50);
$("#car_box_1").animate({top: "58px"}, 50);
```

The animation simply doesn't occur within the FB iFrame, I have tried setting it to higher values, lower values etc. 
Also, the callback IS called.

Does anyone have any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera. It´s seems a security issue, because javascript don´t let you access elements on iframes from another domain!

Comment: Hey :) Thanks for your answer! I actually figured this out a few days layer with the help of a co-worker. It was not a bug in my animations but simply IE that couldn't handle CSS loaded through AJAX and that cascaded to cause this error :) Thanks!